# Angular Translate Use with Directive

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc-4, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angular-ui

Here's [fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/UGLjh/16/) .... I am trying to update the content of directive with $translate  and using the controller. Is there any other generic way to do the same thing(link in directive?? ) .If i want to use same directive in one Controller only then this approach might not work.
Basically how can i get rid of controllers ?

HTML

```
    <terms-conditions conditions="conditions" checked="checked"></terms-conditions>   <br>
    <button class="btn-primary" ng-disabled="!checked" >Submit</button>
      <hr>


</div>

    <div name="info" ng-controller="myCtrl2">
 <terms-conditions conditions="conditions" checked="checked"></terms-conditions>  <br>
       <button class="btn-primary" ng-disabled="!checked">Submit</button>
      <hr>

</div>
</div>
```

js file

```
var demo = angular.module('demo', ['pascalprecht.translate']);
demo.directive("termsConditions",function(){
return {
    restrict:"E",
    scope:{
        conditions:'=',
        checked:'='
    },
    template:
    "<div class='terms row'><span class='col-md-12'>{{conditions}}</span></div><br><input type='checkbox' ng-model='checked'><span>Yes, I agree to the terms and condtions</span>"
}

});
demo.config(function ($translateProvider) {
   $translateProvider.translations('en', {
        PRODUCT_NAME: 'NAME',
        TERMS_CONDITIONS:"TERMS & CONDITIONS",
        OTHER_TERMS_CONDITIONS: 'OTHER TERMS & CONDITIONS',
        AGREEMENT: 'Yes, I agree to the terms and condtions ',

    });

    $translateProvider.preferredLanguage('en');

})
demo.controller("myCtrl1", function ($scope, $translate) {
$translate('TERMS_CONDITIONS')
    .then(function (translatedValue) {
        $scope.conditions = translatedValue;
    });

})
demo.controller("myCtrl2", function ($scope, $translate) {
$translate('OTHER_TERMS_CONDITIONS')
    .then(function (translatedValue) {
        $scope.conditions = translatedValue;
    });

})
```

CSS

```
span {
font-weight:bold;
}
.terms{font-weight: normal;
width: 500px;
height: 50px;
overflow-y: scroll;
padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
border-style: solid;
border-color: #666666;
border-width: 1px;}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no reason you can't use the $translate provider in your directive.  Just inject it as a dependency.  If you want to get remove responsibility from the controller for triggering the translation, you can use just put those as attributes in your html.

Example (not tested, but this is close to what should work):

The html (generalize the directive to simply use an attribute and use whatever markup you want per translated element)

```
<div translated="TERMS_CONDITIONS">{{text}}</div>
```

The directive (create a new scope, use the translate service, and bind to whatever value you put in translated attribute)

```
demo.directive("translated",['$translate', '$scope', function($translate, $scope){
  return {
    restrict:"AEC",
    scope:true,
    link: function(scope, el, attr){
      $scope.text = '';
      $translate('TERMS_CONDITIONS')
        .then(function (translatedValue) {
          $scope.conditions = translatedValue;
        });          
    }
  }
]);
```

Comment: Thanks Calvin :) actually i got it  the same way. Sorry forget to attach the solution here.